# Accessing Sessions Variables in code behind

Tags: asp.net

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Session["Authenticated"] )
        {
            Response.Redirect( "index.aspx", false );
        }
    }
```

Once they login I set the session to true.  Basically, if they don't have an active session I want them re-directed back to the index/login page.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this check

```
if(Session["Authenticated"] == null || !(bool)Session["Authenticated"])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cookie, you can store a marker in your cookie so you can tell the difference between **"fresh browser + new session" and "old browser + expired session"**.

Below is sample code that will redirect the user to an expired page if the session has expired.

```
void Session_OnStart(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
  HttpCookieCollection cookies = context.Request.Cookies; 
  if (cookies["starttime"] == null) { 
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("starttime", DateTime.Now.ToString()); 
    cookie.Path = "/"; 
    context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); 
  } 
  else { 
    context.Response.Redirect("expired.aspx"); 
  } 
}
```

And if you are trying to implement sessions this might help you http://aspalliance.com/1621_Implementing_a_Session_Timeout_Page_in_ASPNET.2